# what is the relationship between iodbc, freeTDS and odbc driver?

Tags: php, odbc

what i know about odbc is a set of APIs to connect programming language and the database. For example in php on mac, if I need to connect to MSSerever,I may need to use iodbc for selecting php odbc driver. But what is freeTDS for? what is the correct process to connect with the msserver 2000 with PHP  on my mac?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ODBC is an API for accessing database drivers.

ODBC specifies that between the application and the driver, there must be a driver manager which manages loading the driver, unloading it, doing mapping from ODBC 2.x to 3.x function calls (and vice versa), and a few other things. iODBC is actually a driver manager, and one of iODBC, unixODBC, or another driver manager is required for all applications using ODBC drivers. (You can link directly against ODBC drivers, however this is almost never supported by the drivers themselves)

freeTDS is an implementation of the SQL Server wire protocol, you would use this if you had an application which needed to communicate directly with SQL Server. In the vast majority of cases, you would use the ODBC driver for SQL Server instead of using the wire protocol directly.

Unfortunately, at this point in time, Microsoft does not have an ODBC driver for SQL Server on the Mac platform. Tableau 8.2 (http://www.tableausoftware.com/public/blog/2013/09/tableau-public-mac-2130) is in public beta and contains connectivity for SQL Server on Mac which Simba Technologies (http://www.simba.com) built. You may want to talk to them regarding getting access.